# How to run NUnit test with parameters via dotnet test command?

Tags: .net, nunit

I try to run tests via console but it doesn't work. I think that I need fix test parameter format. Parameter value can has few words.
Could you help with correct string to run tests with parameters?

I have tried to change quotes and comma but it doesn't help.

Example:

```
dotnet test myProject --filter "Name=MyTest('My parameter value',null)"
```

Error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: null)

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
```

Also I have tried to encode comma to URL style but it doesn't work too...

Example:

```
dotnet test myProject --filter Name=MyTest('My parameter value'%2Cnull)"
```

Error:

```
An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://nunit3testexecutor/': Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&'. Specify the correct format and try again. Note that the incorrect format can lead to no test getting executed.
```

P.S. Problem only when test has parameters. Without parameters all works OK as it described in tutorials and official documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for myself. Because it's so complicated to find out how to work with quotes in the console (maybe it's impossible for NUnit), I have decided to use categories as an ID of tests. In this case, each test has a unique ID and I can run them easily across the console via the "Category" filter.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a command-line program, so whatever you type has to pass through the command-line processing of your operating system before it ever reaches the `dotnet` command to be processed.

Of course, command-line processing is different on each operating system and you haven't said what OS you are using. I'm going to assume Windows for this answer.

Another thing you haven't shown is the Type of the argument to the `MyTest` method. NUnit will use its string representation, which is why we need that info to give a good answer. So I will go ahead and assume the argument is a string.

Given the above assumptions, you would need to type something like this...

```
dotnet test myProject --filter "Name=MyTest(\"My parameter value\")"
```

I didn't include the second parameter, which is null, because I don't even have enough info for a guess. :-)

Comment: @Charie Hi! Thank you for answer!
I use windows. I tried your answer, but I got the same result. Also I have tried to use ' as outer brackets and " for inner but I have the same problem...

Comment: We probably need to see the header of the test you are trying to run in order to better understand. WRT quotes... there are no options. Use double quotes and escape any inner double quotes with a backslash. This is not XML!

Comment: Suggestion... to see how command-line args with special chars are interpreted, just write a one-line script to echo the arguments to the console.